# How to extract specific rows from a very complex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, extract

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` of the form. I'll show you a simple example.(In reality, it consists of hundreds of millions of rows of data.). I want to extract the rows corresponding to (energy >= 0.3) when ('type'=22) according to 'event'.

```
df=

  index    event    type    energy    ID
    

    0       a        22      0.3       1
    1       a        0       0.01      2
    2       a        0       0.02      3
    3       a        22      0.21      4
    4       a        0       0.03      5
    5       b        22      0.11      2
    6       b        0       0.02      3
    7       b        22      0.41      4
    8       b        0       0.05      1
    9       b        0       0.01      2
    10      c        22      0.1       1
    11      c        0       0.01      2
    12      c        0       0.02      3
    13      c        22      0.32      4
    14      c        0       0.022     5
    15      c        22      0.1       2
    16      c        0       0.02      3
    17      d        22      0.1       4
    18      d        0       0.05      1
    19      d        0       0.01      2
    20      e        22      0.1       4
    21      e        0       0.05      1
    22      e        0       0.01      2
    23      e        22      0.2       4
    24      e        0       0.05      1
    25      e        0       0.01      2
    26      e        22      0.32      4
    27      e        0       0.05      1
    28      e        0       0.01      2
    29      f        22      0.5       4
    30      f        0       0.05      1
    31      f        0       0.01      2
```

Here is my expected result:

```
df=

  index    event    type   energy    ID
    

    0       a        22      0.3       1
    1       a        0       0.01      2
    2       a        0       0.02      3
    7       b        22      0.41      4
    8       b        0       0.05      1
    9       b        0       0.01      2
    13      c        22      0.32      4
    14      c        0       0.022     5
    26      e        22      0.32      4
    27      e        0       0.05      1
    28      e        0       0.01      2
    29      f        22      0.5       4
    30      f        0       0.05      1
    31      f        0       0.01      2
```

Comment: kindly explain your logic a bit better; take for instance event `a`, kindly explain the output dataframe for `a` based on your logic

Comment: It looks to me like you want to select all rows where `energy >= 0.3` IF `type = 22`, but if `type != 22`, just select the row regardless of `energy`. Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "according to 'event'"?

Comment: So, according to your expected output, you get rid of the last two rows of event `a`. Why?

Comment: 'type = 0' belongs to 'type =22'
So I need to find the row corresponding to 'type == 22 & energy >= 0.3'.

Comment: It looks to me like you want to select all rows where energy >= 0.3 IF type = 22, but if type != 22, just select the row regardless of energy. Is that correct? << It is correct

Comment: You can ignore "according to 'event'".

Comment: My explanation skills have gone down. I'm sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239998/discussion-between--and-user17242583).

Comment: Did you understand what I said?

Comment: It's ok @김수환 - my understanding skills have corresponding gone down as well... :)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, but one more thing: why are the last two rows of event `a` dropped?

Comment: I will explain 'event c' as an example. The 'index' of 'event c' is 10-16. And 'index 10~12' is one set (A) belonging to 'index 10, type 22, energy 0.1'. 'index 13~14' is one set (B) belonging to 'index 13, type 22, energy 0.32'. 'index 15~16' is a set (C) belonging to 'index 15, type 22, energy 0.1'. (type = 22 & type = 0) belonging to 'type = 22 & energy >= 0.3' should be output. Therefore, in 'event c', what I need is a set (B) with 'index 15~16'.

Comment: The reason that the last two rows are dropped in 'event a' is that (index 3 & 4) corresponding to (energy = 0.21) is dropped because the energy of (index 3, type 22) is 0.21.

Comment: IS this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300487/how-to-output-a-pandas-dataframe-that-satisfies-a-special-condition ? Please don't post questions twice. It's confusing.