# How to output a Pandas DataFrame that satisfies a special condition?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, extract

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` of the form. I'll show you a simple example. (In reality, it consists of hundreds of millions of rows of data.).

When `(type = 0)` belongs to `(type = 22)`, I want to output `(type=22 and type=0)` belonging to `(type=22 & energy >= 0.3)`.

I will explain `event c` as an example.

The 'index' of `event c` is 10-16.

And `index 10~12` is one set (A) belonging to `index 10, type 22, energy 0.1`.

`index 13~14` is one set (B) belonging to `index 13, type 22, energy 0.32`.

`index 15~16` is a set (C) belonging to `index 15, type 22, energy 0.1`.

`(type = 22 & type = 0)` belonging to `type = 22 & energy >= 0.3` should be output.

Therefore, in `event c`, what I need is a set (B) with `index 15~16`.
In `event d`, `(type = 22 & type = 0)` is not output because there is nothing that satisfies the condition `(type = 22 & energy >= 0.3)`.

My source DataFrame

```
df=

  index    event    type    energy    ID
    

    0       a        22      0.3       1
    1       a        0       0.01      2
    2       a        0       0.02      3
    3       a        22      0.21      4
    4       a        0       0.03      5
    5       b        22      0.11      2
    6       b        0       0.02      3
    7       b        22      0.41      4
    8       b        0       0.05      1
    9       b        0       0.01      2
    10      c        22      0.1       1
    11      c        0       0.01      2
    12      c        0       0.02      3
    13      c        22      0.32      4
    14      c        0       0.022     5
    15      c        22      0.1       2
    16      c        0       0.02      3
    17      d        22      0.1       4
    18      d        0       0.05      1
    19      d        0       0.01      2
    20      e        22      0.1       4
    21      e        0       0.05      1
    22      e        0       0.01      2
    23      e        22      0.2       4
    24      e        0       0.05      1
    25      e        0       0.01      2
    26      e        22      0.32      4
    27      e        0       0.05      1
    28      e        0       0.01      2
    29      f        22      0.5       4
    30      f        0       0.05      1
    31      f        0       0.01      2
```

Here is my expected result:

```
df=

  index    event    type   energy    ID
    

    0       a        22      0.3       1
    1       a        0       0.01      2
    2       a        0       0.02      3
    7       b        22      0.41      4
    8       b        0       0.05      1
    9       b        0       0.01      2
    13      c        22      0.32      4
    14      c        0       0.022     5
    26      e        22      0.32      4
    27      e        0       0.05      1
    28      e        0       0.01      2
    29      f        22      0.5       4
    30      f        0       0.05      1
    31      f        0       0.01      2
```

Comment: Each set `A,B,C` strating by `22` ? In type are only `22 or 0` ?

Comment: Are those "events" collisions of particles?

Comment: 'type' is always 0 or 22.

'event' is the particle number.

Answer (score 1):

If each group by `event` start by `type=22` and there are only `type=0,22` you can create helper groups by compare with cumulative sum, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for repeated `type=22` rows, compare and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#if necessary filter only 0,22 rows
#df = df[df['type'].isin([0,22])]

g = df['type'].eq(22).cumsum()
df = df[df.groupby(['event',g])['energy'].transform('first') >= 0.3]
print (df)
      event  type  energy  ID
index                        
0         a    22   0.300   1
1         a     0   0.010   2
2         a     0   0.020   3
7         b    22   0.410   4
8         b     0   0.050   1
9         b     0   0.010   2
13        c    22   0.320   4
14        c     0   0.022   5
26        e    22   0.320   4
27        e     0   0.050   1
28        e     0   0.010   2
29        f    22   0.500   4
30        f     0   0.050   1
31        f     0   0.010   2
```